# grep log file in a remote host

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rhel

I'm trying to grep a string in the log file in a remote host. but I'm having trouble to return the echo to the host where I'm running the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
#dt=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
#HHMM=$(date '+%H:%M')
key="keys/cash_prod_key"



if
        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -qni $key user@host "cat /var/log/FILE_send.log | grep FILENAME | grep -i success"\;
then
        echo "Success"
fi
```

I don't think this is the most correct way to do it.

Comment: It would help if you can explain what you mean by "return the echo".  What do you expect to see from the script, and what do you actually see?   I suspect that you don't need the backslash and semi-colon `\;` at the end of the `ssh` command, because that will cause `grep` to search only for lines containing `success;` (success followed by a semi-colon).  You probably do not need the backslash/semi-colon at all.

Comment: @RobertL The escaped `;` would be sent over to the remote host, but it would be unescaped there, meaning it would not be part of the pattern used by `grep`. To be part of the pattern, it would have to be escaped as `\\\;` or as `\;` _inside_ the double quotes.

Comment: @RobertL when I run the script it doesn't return the echo success.

Comment: @anmoreira Does it output _anything_? Does the log file actually contain the text that you are grepping for (log in on the remote host and check)?

Comment: @Kusalananda it doesn't return nothing. No é ho and no error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was [an incorrect host name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510853/grep-log-file-in-a-remote-host/510867?noredirect=1#comment944690_510867).

This answer is instead focusing on how to write the code in a better way.

You don't need to run the complete pipeline on the remote host.  Running complicated commands on the command line with `ssh` is rather error prone, not least from a quoting point of view.

Instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

key="keys/cash_prod_key"

ssh_args=( -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -qni "$key" user@host )

if ssh "${ssh_args[@]}" cat /var/log/FILE_send.log |
   grep -F 'FILENAME' |
   grep -q -i -F 'success'
then
    echo 'Success'
fi
```

This would run only the `cat` on the remote host and then run the two `grep` commands locally.

I've also added the `-F` flag to the `grep` commands, assuming that the strings used as patterns are *not* regular expressions but literal strings that you'd like to search for.  The last `grep` uses `-q` as we're not actually interested in *seeing* the output, just in whether it contains the string `success` or not.

To make it easier to read, I've put the arguments used with `ssh` into an array that I later use in the call, and I've also made the lines a bit shorter by simply inserting newlines after the pipe symbols.  The script is still syntactically correct.  Also note that any expansion of variable etc. should always be double quoted, unless you know in what contexts [this is not needed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694).

Note that I'm assuming that the `ssh` command is invoked in the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kusalananda, I tried your answer and as mine, i do not receive the echo on the host where I run the script.
I do not receive any error also.

Comment: @anmoreira In that case, I presume that the text is not in the file, or the patterns that you use are matching the wrong things.

Comment: found the problem, the hostname was slightly incorrect since the host is part of cluster